# Unable to login into Knowage GUI

Tags: fiware-knowage

After setting up Knowage as per steps given on my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50562673/edit, i was getting error of Table does not exist.

Then, after downloading “`mysql-dbscripts-6_2_0-RC_20180509.zip`” from https://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=442 and executing SQL scripts for missing tables, I could start Knowage.

On startup it is having below error in “`knowage.lo`g” file.

> [localhost-startStop-1] 28 May 2018 07:55:06,898 ERROR
>   it.eng.spagobi.commons.utilities.SpagoBIUtilities.readJndiResource:317
>   - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [resource_path] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [resource_path].

I opened login page in browser and when submitting with credentials “`biadmin/biadmin`”, I am getting following errors.

Any idea what is wrong or what setting is left?

**Knowage.log**

```
root@AzureFiwareInstance:/home/babbarkrishan/knowage/Knowage-Server-CE/logs# vi knowage.log
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter.doFilter(SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at it.eng.spagobi.security.InternalSecurityServiceSupplierImpl.checkAuthentication(InternalSecurityServiceSupplierImpl.java:76)
        at it.eng.spagobi.security.InternalSecurityServiceSupplierImpl.checkAuthentication(InternalSecurityServiceSupplierImpl.java:110)
        at it.eng.spagobi.commons.services.LoginModule.service(LoginModule.java:257)
       at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.invokeServiceBusiness(DefaultPage.java:352)
        at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.nextStep(DefaultPage.java:302)
        at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.DefaultPage.service(DefaultPage.java:202)
        at it.eng.spago.dispatching.module.ModuleCoordinator.service(ModuleCoordinator.java:102)
        at it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.AdapterHTTP.service(AdapterHTTP.java:436)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.utilities.exceptions.SpagoBIRuntimeException: Cannot initialize JWT algorithm
        at it.eng.spagobi.services.common.JWTSsoService.<clinit>(JWTSsoService.java:59)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Secret cannot be null
        at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.HMACAlgorithm.getSecretBytes(HMACAlgorithm.java:40)
        at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.HMACAlgorithm.<init>(HMACAlgorithm.java:34)
        at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm.HMAC256(Algorithm.java:144)
        at it.eng.spagobi.services.common.JWTSsoService.<clinit>(JWTSsoService.java:56)
        ... 40 more
```

Thanks,

Krishan

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because in installation setup whole db schema was not created.
Only few tables were created.
I tried creating all tables manually and then was getting above error.

After debugging a lot i found below error with MySQL (5.7.22 version)

```
SQL Error (1067): Invalid default value for 'TIME_IN'
```

I fixed this issue using following command.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

After that I tried fresh installation of Knowage and it worked correctly.

Regards,

Krishan